# How to get that the limit exceeded when I use limit() on a range of items from stream using Java 8 lambda?

Tags: java-8

How should I know without using another condition to compare the map.size() with limitValue, that the limit was exceeding when my stream iterated?
Here,
 for limitValue = 3, it should return false.
 for limitValue = 4, it should return true.
I can not use an outside int field as it must be final to be used inside lambda.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "foo");
        map.put(2, "bar");
        map.put(3, "baz");
        int limitValue = 3;

        String result = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .limit(limitValue)
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with "using another condition to compare the map.size() with limitValue"? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What's wrong with `boolean exceeded = limitValue > map.size()`? I mean, why can't you use this?

Answer (score 1):

> I can not use an outside int field as it must be final to be used
>   inside lambda.

Yes, this is because, within a lambda expression, you can only reference local variables whose value doesn’t change (in java).

This is a good thing in a way as mutating a variable(s) inside a lambda is not thread safe when executing in parallel.

So, the system is helping you prevent such scenarios at compile time by allowing only final or effectively final variables to be used in lambdas.

Note, this restriction only holds for local variables.

Anyhow, my advice is not to mutate variables that are not solely contained within a given function itself as it introduces a *side-effect* and *side-effects* in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged.

Keep things simple and proceed with the below approach.

```
 boolean exceeded = limitValue > map.size();
```